# Crispy sweet potato (yam) fries in a deep fryer?

Tags: frying, deep-frying, french-fries, sweet-potatoes

I bought a roto deep fryer recently. But everytime I make yam fries, they end up being soggy.

My process: I cut the sweet potato fries to about 1/4 inch. I follow deep fryer instructions of preheating to 370'F before dropping the basket. From there, I fry a full basket for about 12-14 minutes.

The yam fries always come out soggy.

Any suggestions to improve the process?

Comment: [Yams != Sweet Potatoes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-wV_58DHkLM)

Answer (score 3):

I would also cut down on the "Full Basket" to lessen the Oil Temp Recovery. Try just a few handfuls at a time to keep the temp above 325'F. Frying time per batch should only be between 1 - 2 minutes.

Comment: It's a "roto deep fryer" so might take twice as long lol. But now you're making me think that perhaps I'm cooking for too long, and maybe that's why they're soaking up extra oil.

Answer (score 2):

You could try par-boiling the fries first. Drop your cut yams into boiling water until they begin to soften (about 5-7 minutes.) Remove them and let the cool completely before frying.
12-14 minutes seems like an awfully long time to keep something immersed in boiling oil. The par-cook method, while increasing overall preparation time will increase the quality of your fries.

Comment: I'll give it a try. The "roto deep fryer" is only half-immersed in oil, and rotates the basket through that oil; so it might be that it cooks half as fast as a regular deep fryer. I'm pretty sure the instructions said 12-14 minutes for a full basket, but now you're making me doubt myself lol. There is a decal on the front of the device that shows 8 minutes for fries, which I'm thinking is a half-basket. But that's for regular potato fries, so not sure about sweet potato.

Comment: Certainly in the oven sweet potatoes are quicker to soften than normal potatoes (wedges, jackets)